# Create multiple attribute for one Element with DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

How can I create more than one attribute for a DOM Element?

Here I have one attribute

```
$data = $xml->createElement('enclosure', $rssdata["nNr"]);
$enclosure = $xml->createAttribute('type');
$enclosure->value = 'image/jpeg';
$data->appendChild($enclosure);
$item->appendChild($data);
```

But I need two attributes like the export here for URL

```
<enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="">1</enclosure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add three more lines:

```
$data = $xml->createElement('enclosure', $rssdata["nNr"]);

$enclosure = $xml->createAttribute('type'); # creating attribute 1
$enclosure->value = 'image/jpeg';           # setting value
$data->appendChild($enclosure);             # adding attribute to element

$url = $xml->createAttribute('url');  # creating attribute 2
$url->value = '';                     # setting value
$data->appendChild($url);             # adding attribute to element

$item->appendChild($data);
```

If you have many attributes to add, you might consider creating a function to reduce code duplication.

Your variable names may be confusing. If you rename `$enclosure` and `$data` your code might become clearer and easier to read:

```
$enclosureElement = $xml->createElement('enclosure', $rssdata["nNr"]);

$typeAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('type'); # creating attribute 1
$typeAttribute->value = 'image/jpeg';           # setting value
$enclosureElement->appendChild($typeAttribute); # adding attribute to element

$urlAttribute = $xml->createAttribute('url');  # creating attribute 2
$urlAttribute->value = '';                     # setting value
$enclosureElement->appendChild($urlAttribute); # adding attribute to element

$item->appendChild($enclosureElement);
```

Comment: With `->createAttribute()` you can set the `value` as well - just add it as 2nd argument. Even easier: Use `setAttribute()`. No need to create one.

Answer (score 3):

With PHP's DOM extension, you can more easily add one or more attributes to a **DOMElement** by using the `DOMElement::setAttribute` method.

Saying that `$enclosure` is the `DOMElement` for the `<enclosure>` element in your question:

```
$enclosure->setAttribute("type", "image/jpeg");
$enclosure->setAttribute("url", "");
```

Just adds those two attributes you're asking for. You can do one, two or N attributes that way.

> *Background Info:* In XML an element can only have one attribute with the same name.

Comment: Finally one right _and useful_ answer :P

Answer (score 1):

Just add another one the way you added the first one.

```
$urlAttr = $xml->createAttribute('url');
...
```