# Adding attr tag in html via PHP

Tags: php, html, html-object

I would like to add another property and value into my HTML object,
but instead, it's replacing the current value.

This is what I've coded so far in my PHP file.

```
function htmlEncode ( $html ){

$html = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $html);
$html = html_entity_decode($html);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $div){

    foreach ($div->attributes as $attr) {

        if($div->nodeName == "h2"){
            $class = $attr->nodeName;
            $className = $attr->nodeValue;
            $div->setAttribute("aria-label", $div->nodeValue);  

            $result = [
                 "tagName" => $div->nodeName, 
                 "value" => $div->nodeValue, 
                 $class=> $className, 
                 $attr->nodeName => $attr->nodeValue
            ];
        } else {
            $result[] = [
                 "tagName" => $div->nodeName, 
                 "value" => $div->nodeValue,
                 $attr->nodeName => $attr->nodeValue
           ];
        }
    }       
}

$json = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

return $json;
}
```

but when I run the code

```
echo json_encode($attr->nodeName);
```

I get the two attributes:

"class" "aria-label"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code.
Changes done:

```
1. $class[] = array();

2. $class[$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
3. Removed `class` from results
4. Added 
            foreach($class as $key=>$classValues){
                if(!empty($classValues)){
                     $result[$key] = $classValues;     
                }
             }
```

Complete code:

```
function htmlEncode ( $html ){

$html = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $html);
$html = html_entity_decode($html);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $div){
    $class[] = array();
    foreach ($div->attributes as $attr) {
        if($div->nodeName == "h2"){
            $class[$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue;
            $div->setAttribute("aria-label", $div->nodeValue);

            $result = [
                 "tagName" => $div->nodeName, 
                 "value" => $div->nodeValue,
                 $attr->nodeName => $attr->nodeValue
            ];
            foreach($class as $key=>$classValues){
                 if(!empty($classValues)){
                        $result[$key] = $classValues;     
                 }
            }
        } else {
            $result[] = [
                 "tagName" => $div->nodeName, 
                 "value" => $div->nodeValue,
                 $attr->nodeName => $attr->nodeValue
           ];
        }
    }       
}

$json = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

return $json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new line

```
$div->setAttribute("class", $div->nodeValue);
$div->setAttribute("aria-label", $div->nodeValue);
```

Comment: I understand that, but what I want is to return both attributes instead of replacing "aria-label" with "class".

Comment: Ohh in this case, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250820/create-multiple-attribute-for-one-element-with-dom